# How to create a stored procedure to update Employee table?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to update the salary on an employee table that I have created. My procedure has to accept two values one for the `emp_id` and the other for the new salary (`emp_salary`). Below is my employee table code:

```
create table emp 
(
     emp_id  int, 
     emp_name varchar(30), 
     salary numeric(10, 2), 
     dept_code char(4)
)

insert into emp 
values (1, 'Jones', 11111.00, 'SALE'), (2, 'Smith', 22222.00, 'SALE'),
       (3, 'Potter', 33333.00, 'TECH'), (4, 'Clinton', 44444.00, 'MNGT')
```

Below is my stored procedure code:

```
create procedure usp_update_Imani
   (@emp_id int, @salary int)
as
begin
    update emp 
    set salary = salary * 1.1
    where emp_id = 1, 2, 3, 4;
End;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, just reference the parameters of the stored procedure in your `update` statement:

```
create procedure usp_update_Imani(@emp_id int, @salary int)
as
begin
    update emp set salary = @salary where emp_id = @emp_id;
end;
```

Compile it, and test it as follows:

```
exec usp_update_Imani(1, 121212)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you want to pass in the new salary since you have a parameter for the value. Also, you are passing in the emp_id so not sure why you are trying to update all of them (the syntax you have there would fail anyway). Here is how you would create a procedure to update the salary for a single emp_id to a new value.

```
create procedure usp_update_Imani
(
    @emp_id int
    , @salary int
) AS
    set nocount on;

    UPDATE emp set salary = @salary
    where emp_id = @emp_id
```